# How can I add a Dexterity content type as the default view?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm trying to set a folder default view as a Dexterity content type that I created. But I see that Dexterity content types aren't in the list of possible default content views for folders. Why? Is there an option that I must set in the content type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content items are listed as candidate default pages if:

- the object is not a container type

or

- the object portal type is listed in the `default_page_types` of your `site_properties` property sheet. Find that in the ZMI (site settings -> Zope Management Interface -> `portal_properties`).

  The `default_page_types` property is a list of `portal_type` ids; for Dexterity types that is usually a dotted name (the [Dexterity manual](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/schema-driven-types/the-fti) uses `example.conference.presenter` for example).

Comment: Its works! But why the first restriction? May be I want to put a content object that is containing its own images and other resources.

Comment: @DanielHernández: Sorry, I worded this wrong. All non-container types are listed *and* any type explicitly listed in `default_page_types`.

Comment: When a type is considered a non-container? I set dexterity type having no `allowed_content_types` empty and `filter_content_types` True but the content type is not listed to be set as the default view.

Comment: The code tests for the `.is_folderish` attribute. It *could* be that dexterity types don't have that attribute and thus through acquisition this is looked up on the parent (which is always a container and thus `.is_folderish` will be `True`).

Comment: Clarification: the `.is_folderish` attribute is a catalog index, and it uses the `.isPrincipiaFolderish` attribute on objects. These *are* present on Dexterity content types.

Comment: I was [asking about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177286/how-to-add-the-is-folderish-attribute-to-dexterity-objects) a few seconds before I read your comment. You guess that I could don't understand that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Plone 5.x**

- Go to `Site Setup > Content Settings` control panel
- Select your (dexteity-)contenttype in the `Workflow, visibility and versioning settings for your content types` dropdown.
- check `Can be used as a default page`

  (default_page_types property has been removed from ZMI)